# kendoMaskedTextBox property mask, date format M/d/yyyy issue

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker

I tried using kendoMaskedTextBox for kendo datepicker.
(I want to let user to press the date by keyboard, and see mask).

Till now I used format MM/dd/yyyy and it worked well.
Now I change the format to M/d/yyyy.
And when I give to the datePicker value with month of 2 digits- the datePicker input disrupted.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The MaskedTextBox is designed to be used with fixed-length user input. The `M/d/yyyy` format has a variable length, so it cannot be used with a mask.